# Combining wget and aws s3 cp to upload data to S3 without saving locally

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, wget

I have a url that points to a file (.tif) and would like to upload the file to Amazon S3. I currently download the file to an EC2 instance using `wget` and then upload to an S3 bucket using `aws s3 cp` in linux command line. I was wondering if you could directly pipe (not sure about correct nomenclature) the file to S3 without saving to the EC2 instance first.

Comment: So, you want to load data from a URL you have directly to S3. Is this correct?

Comment: correct. The aws s3 cp command takes {local_path} as an argument and not a URL. I already have aws set up so it would be great to use the official aws cli tools

Comment: Bonus: instead of first scraping a website and then uploading, I would like to do it in one comment using wget --recursive

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assumptions:

- `<url>` is the url you want to read
- `<s3_bucket>` is the name of the S3 bucket you want to load the files to
- `<s3_key>` is the key in the bucket (like the file name)

`wget -qO- <url> | aws s3 cp - s3://<s3_bucket>/<s3_key>`

The first portion of this grabs the file and outputs to standard output. The second part of this reads from standard output and copies it to the named S3 location.

Comment: this is great.  -q quiet -O output and - is the pipe

Comment: is there a way to combine your answer with the --recursive flag of wget to get all files of https://gis1.servirglobal.net/data/esi/12WK/2001/ ?

Comment: Is the `q` ncessary to ensure clean output to stdout? Or just to keep the tty clear?

Comment: Answering my own question, after checking hashes of the files, the `q` is not necessary, just keeps the console empty.

Comment: If the size of the stream is greater than 50 GB, specify the expected-size parameter or else you'll run into this error: An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the UploadPart operation: Part number must be an integer between 1 and 10000, inclusive. For reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Answer (score 1):

Mount the S3 bucket as a drive then wget directly inside it

I used this tutorial and it worked out perfectly for me because i had a huge dataset (5TB) i  needed to download directly

https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/amazon-s3-as-a-file-system